# how do I zip a whole folder tree in unix, but only certain files?

Tags: unix, zip

I've been stuck on a little unix command line problem.

I have a website folder (4gb) I need to grab a copy of, but just the .php, .html, .js and .css files (which is only a couple hundred kb).

I'm thinking ideally, there is a way to zip or tar a whole folder but only grabbing certain file extensions, while retaining subfolder structures. Is this possible and if so, how?

I did try doing a whole zip, then going through and excluding certain files but it seemed a bit excessive.

I'm kinda new to unix.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might get better results if you ask this on serverfault.com (a sysadmin specific site)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Switch into the website folder, then run

```
zip -R foo '*.php' '*.html' '*.js' '*.css'
```

You can also run this from outside the website folder:

```
zip -r foo website_folder -i '*.php' '*.html' '*.js' '*.css'
```

Comment: This won't find matching files in subdirectories.

Comment: per the zip manpage, you have to quote the arguments with single quotes ... otherwise, I suspect that the shell will glob them before passing to zip

Comment: @Ted: In the test I performed it did recurse subdirectories.

Comment: I've run man zip on a few different flavors of unix and they're all subtly different.  You may or may not need single quotes around each of the patterns, as kdgregory states.

Comment: Definitely put single quotes around the patterns to match, otherwise the shell will expand them before executing `zip` and you'll just end up with matching files in the current directory.

Comment: This worked a treat with the quotation marks. I didn't try it without. Thanks heaps! Seems like the easiest of all the solutions.

Comment: I tried zip -r foo website_folder -i 'test*' and also zip -R foo website_folder -i 'test*'. It didn't work for me. the -i didn't find the files in the subdirectories. Below answer from Nick did the job.

Comment: Notice the case-sensitive -r. Only lowercase "-r" did the job here.

Answer (score 42):

You can use `find` and `grep` to generate the file list, then pipe that into `zip`

e.g.

```
find . | egrep "\.(html|css|js|php)$" | zip -@ test.zip
```

(`-@` tells zip to read a file list from stdin)

Comment: If you have a large number of non-matching files, it would be slightly more efficient to do something like `find . -iname \*.html -o -iname \*.css -o -iname \*.js -o -iname \*.php` instead of `find . | grep ...`.

Comment: beautiful solution

Answer (score 7):

This is how I managed to do it, but I also like ghostdog74's version.

```
tar -czvf archive.tgz `find  test/ | egrep ".*\.html|.*\.php"`
```

You can add extra extensions by adding them to the regex.

Comment: you may run into issues with the size of the argument list -- see xargs

Answer (score 4):

you may want to use find(GNU) to find all your php,html etc files.then tar them up

```
find /path -type f \( -iname "*.php" -o -iname "*.css" -o -iname "*.js" -o -iname "*.ext" \) -exec tar -r --file=test.tar "{}" +;
```

after that you can zip it up

Comment: the problem with this approach is that it will exec tar for each file

Comment: yes it does. a better approach is to use zip -R as one of you have posted.

Answer (score 4):

I liked Nick's answer, but, since this is a programming site, why not use Ant to do this. :)

Then you can put in a parameter so that different types of files can be zipped up.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html

Comment: I found ant useful, and the documentation is pretty easy to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a shell script to copy files based on a pattern/expression into a new folder, zip the contents and then delete the folder. Now, as for the actual syntax of it, ill leave that to you :D.

Comment: Copy 4Gb of data? I think this should be used as a last report.

Comment: You wouldnt copying the entire directory - only the files that match the pattern. That way when you create the zip you can just say zip all, then delete.

Comment: @MitMaro the OP says it's just a few of hundres of KiB... anyway, an improved version could be done just links links instead of copying (if symbolic links, then use -h with tar)... and that way you could reuse that view of the folder for further backups :-)

Comment: @fortran: Entirely missed that.

my apologies barfoon this is not that bad of an idea.